# Find probability density function for random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f(x)=\chi_{(-\infty,-1]}(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}$. Moreoever, consider $h(x)=e^x$.

Is $h(X)$ a random variable with probability density function?

---

First of all, $h(X)$ is a random variable, as $h$ is continuous and $X$ is a random variable; thus, pre-images of measurable sets are measurable.

Now, the task is to find a probability function for $h(X)$, i.e. I need to find a function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
2. $g$ is integrable
3. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\, dx=1$

and, since $g$ is supposed to be the probability function associated with $h(X)$,

$$
P(h(X)\leq a)=\int_{-\infty}^a g(x)\, dx.
$$

Comment: Use $P(h(X) \leq a) = P(X \leq h^{-1}(a)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\min(h^{-1}(a), 1)}1/x^2 dx$ to get the cumulative distribution function of $h(X)$ and then differentiate to get the probability density function

Comment: OK, what I get is the probability density function
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x\ln^2(x)}, & x\leq \frac{1}{e}\\0, & x>\frac{1}{e}\end{cases}
$$
Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any Borel $A \subset \mathbb{R}$,
$$P(h(X) \in A) = P(X \in h^{-1}(A)) = \int_{h^{-1}(A)}f(x)\,dx = \int_{A}f(h^{-1}(y))\frac{1}{|h'(h^{-1}(y)|}\,dy.$$ Hence
$$f_{h(X)}(y) = f_{X}(x)\frac{1}{|h'(x)|}, \text{where }x=h^{-1}(y).$$

Comment: Ok, then I get
$$
f_{h(X)}(y)=\chi_{(-\infty,-1]}(\ln(y))\frac{1}{\lvert y\rvert\ln(y)^2}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
f_{h(X)}(y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{y\ln(y)^2}, & 0<y\leq e^{-1}\\0, & y>e^{-1}\end{cases}
$$
isn't it?